# How to switch between windows in WPF when using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am not totally new to MVVM or WPF but I have this problem where I want to switch from one window to another in WPF using the MVVM pattern. I can get it to work when switching between UserControls, but not Windows. I have looked at the following:

[WPF MVVM Switching Between Usercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095970/wpf-mvvm-switching-between-usercontrols)

[WPF MVVM navigate views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views)

It seems that it almost works, but it goes into break mode after switching window instead of displaying the window.

So what I got so far is: 
   - Two windows (WPF) 
   - A base view model implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and two view models     inheriting from it.

The code below is simply from a simple project I made in order to try to make this work.

I have made the following Datatemplates in the App.xaml as suggested above:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowVM}">
        <local:MainWindow/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SignUpVM}">
        <local:SignUpWindow/>
    </DataTemplate>              
</Application.Resources>
```

My MainWindowVM got a command used to instantiate the new view model in order to change view:

```
    private BaseVM _viewModel;

    public BaseVM ViewModel {
        get => _viewModel;
        set {
            _viewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ICommand SignUpCmd { get; set; }
    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        SignUpCmd = new SignUpCommand(this);
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        ViewModel = new SignUpVM();
    }
```

The corresponding xaml code for the MainWindow:

```
<Grid>        
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Content="Sign Up" Width="100" Height="100" Command="{Binding SignUpCmd}"/>
</Grid>
```

Then for the SignUpWindow the view model and view is simply empty.

So I tried debugging and I can see that it do change view and initializes the SignUpWindow by calling the InitializeComponent method in the constructor:

```
public SignUpWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

But after that it goes into breakmode with the following error:

> **System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException**: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual

So my initial thoughts on why this does not work is that I can not use the 
 local:MainWindow and local:SignUpWindow in the App.xaml, 
 simply because they are Windows. 
 I do not know if this is the proper way of switching between windows and I would really appreciate if someone can spot the error or give an alternative, thanks :)

Comment: The message says you can't add a Window to a Window. so why don't you use UserControls instead of Windows?

Comment: I could use UserControls instead, but it is simply just to know how to switch between Windows for future purposes.

Comment: A window is the container of controls so switching between windows does not make sense when you can switch between controls. You should have one window with several controls.

Comment: Ohh I see, so I would likely not end up in a situation where I would need to switch between Windows assuming the application is well designed, correct?

Comment: Exactly. You most likely need one window for the whole app and a few more for e.g. tools etc

Comment: Great to know and thanks. Now one last question out of curiosity, if I needed to switch between two Windows, would it be possible using the MVVM design pattern or is it one of its weaknesses?

Comment: If you want to switch between windows, you have to instantiate them "manually" like `mainWin = New MainWindow;` and `mainWin .Show();`. And you can even bind them to events in your VM to show them properly without breaking the *MVVM* model.

Comment: Thank you. I will look that up if I need it. For now, I am just going to use UserControls.